# SAS ODBC setup using ssh tunnel via Putty on windows

Tags: ssh, sas, odbc, putty

I am trying to set up SAS ODBC connection to sas server installed on linux.
I have sas ODBC installed on my local (windows)cand now I need to connect to the sas session on the SAS server. 
My approach :
trying to create a port forward using putty on windows and then configuring ODBC.

Is my approach correct.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you trying to use ODBC connection from jobs running on the SAS server to connect to a remote database (e.g. Oracle)? Or are you trying to use ODBC connection from your PC to have a non-sas client be able to read a SAS dataset on the server? Or some other goal?

Comment: I amtrying to use ODBC connection from my PC to have a non-sas client be able to read a SAS dataset on the server